# How to add static value when doing INSERT INTO with SELECT in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two MySQL tables a and b with fields x and y. Table b has 1 extra field z. Table a is in database db1 and b is in db2. I want to copy x and y from a to b and set a static value for z. How can I do that ?

```
db1.a.x -> db2.b.x
db1.a.y -> db2.b.y
4 -> db2.b.z
```

So far I have:

```
"INSERT INTO db2.b (x,y) SELECT x,y FROM db1.a"
```

How do I set db2.b.z to 4 ? I do not want to set a permanent default variable for the table.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`SELECT 4` will give you `4`, so try:

```
INSERT INTO db2.b (x,y,z) SELECT x,y,4 FROM db1.a
```

Answer (score 16):

```
INSERT INTO db2.b (x, y, z) SELECT x, y, 4 FROM db1.a;
```